# CS0019 C# Operator '&&' - magic of deleting

Tags: c#

I have intersting issue. In such option there is the error :

```
  authorized = ("Admin" == login && "0000" == password) ||
                                  ("Petrova" == login && "2222" == password) ||
                                  ("Semenova" == login && "3333" == password) ||
                                  ("Ivanova" == login && "1111" = password) ||
                                  ("Vasileva" == login && "4444" == password);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvrPr.png)

But if delete one string the error dissapears.

```
authorized = ("Admin" == login && "0000" == password) ||
                                  ("Petrova" == login && "2222" == password) ||
                                  ("Semenova" == login && "3333" == password) ||
                                  ("Vasileva" == login && "4444" == password);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjR10.png)

**Does the C# have some claims to "Ivanova"?**

Comment: Please add the error messages as *text* into your question, rather than as images.

Comment: This is a typo - you missed an `=` sign in `"1111" = password`

Answer (score 3):

If you look carefully in the picture with the error, you will see that you missed one =.